# MySQL still using one CPU even though extra CPU added

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I m SQL server DBA. My company just handover one MySQL server to manage which i m still learning. Recently extra CPU has been added to the server due to CPU is 100% but when checked on the server , MySQL still using one CPU only and doesn't utilized other CPU. Is it anything need to configure so that MySQL will use other CPU as well?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  What OS are you using? If Linux, from LX command prompt, mpstat -P ALL 5 3 and press Enter to list the multiprocessor status.

Comment: If on Windows, rgt Clk on This PC / My Computer, Device Manager, Processors for the number of processors.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  MySQL never uses more than one CPU per connection.  It never has, and there is very little hope on the horizon.

Exceptions:

- There are some background threads that many use a small amount of CPU.
- There are a limited number of cases in 8.0 of making use of multiple CPUs.

I would argue that it is not worth much effort to make use of multiple CPUs:

- The orchestration of splitting up a query and recombining is a lot of overhead and complexity.
- Some things virtually prevent using multiple CPUs.  Think `ORDER BY`.
- Many queries are I/O-bound.  Extra cpus don't help in that case.
- The typical "busy" system has many connections doing work.  In that case, many CPUs may actually be used.

Comment: I have the same issue. It's not about the same connection. I stress test with multiple connections/queries and still the queries all end up on 1 CPU reaching 100%, while the other says idle. (Windows 10. Mysql 5.6.10)

Comment: @nl-x - Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And the query that is running when it hits 100%.